# Append 3 new columns based on return from function applied to each row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, anaconda

I have lambda function that is applied to each row an initial dataframe.  It passes a value called IP Into a function and returns 3 values which need to appended to three new columns. I thought returning a series and specifying the new columns names was sufficient but this isn't the case and I get a key length error.  How do I accomplish this given the context?

```
def mainRun():
    df = pd.read_csv('SomeCSV.csv')
    df['IP'] = df['IP'].fillna("0.0.0.0")
    try:
        df[['MatchFound', 'IPBlock', 'Site']] = df.apply(lambda row: rangeChecker(row['IP']), axis=1,result_type='expand')
    except Exception as e:
        print("IPs found --> {}",foundIps)
        print("Error {}",e)

def rangeChecker(rip):
    global foundIps
    ripList = rip.splitlines()
    for i in ripList:
        for index, row in dfa.iterrows():
            try:
                if IPAddress(i) in IPNetwork(row['IPBlock']):
                    foundIps+=1
                    return pd.Series("True", row['IPBlock'], row['Site'])
            except Exception as e:
                break
    return pd.Series("False" "NA" "NA")
```

Comment: Pandas and for loops, two things are incompatible... Look for ready-made functions to implement.

Comment: Not the issue here, the iteration works fine it's the returning of values I am having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved by wrapping the return values in a list.

```
    for i in ripList:
    for index, row in dfa.iterrows():
        try:
            if IPAddress(i) in IPNetwork(row['IPBlock']):
                return ["True", row['IPBlock'], row['Site']] # Works
        except Exception as e:
            break
return ["False", "NA", "NA"] #Works
```

I am well aware that this is not efficient however I am making use of a library (netaddr) to determine if an IP from df A is contained within a list of possible CIDR blocks in df B, however in DFa in many columns are multiple \n delimited IPs so they need to split and compared individually.